# Friendly url only for url

Tags: apache, mod-rewrite

Sorry for the bad title name... The problem is that I am using the standard rewrite like:

```
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?q=$1 [L,QSA]
```

But it also rewrites paths to all html included files like jquery, css and etc... So, when i try to reach `domain.com/templates/js/jquery.min.js` - my php script throws exeption because it does not find the desired parameter. I also tried to add [a-z] but it didn't help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try the following:

```
RewriteRule ^([a-z0-9]*)$ index.php?q=$1 [L,QSA]
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to add some conditions to exclude legit requests:

```
# if the request isn't for an existing file
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
# if the request isn't for an existing directory
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
# then rewrite the entire request to index.php
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?q=$1 [L,QSA]
```

Since `/templates/js/jquery.min.js` is a request for an existing file, the first condition will fail and the request won't get rewritten to index.php.

Comment: @user1692333 What URL are you going to that links to that script?

Comment: domain.name/pagestatus, but it also catches domain.name/themres/js/jquery.js